# Spring applicationContext configuration for scheduled methods

Tags: spring

I'm working on a Spring Roo web app, and need to use a Scheduled method that runs in background every certain time, then I added some
lines to my applicationContext.xml, and that method ran ok, but then
occured that the app wasn't able to set up/read the
transactionManager, the console says `The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'tx:annotation-driven'.`

I already searched, and found in this site, 2 or 3 answers to this error message, such aS:

1. add `xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx` to the
   header [already done]
2. add `component:scan` before `tx:annotation` [already done] but when I try to run my app on the server, it throws
   a `HTTP Status 404 The Requested Resource is not available`, could you
   help me to fix the xml file?

this is my applicationContext.xml file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd                 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd                 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/task/spring-task-3.0.xsd"
    xmlns:task="http://www.springframework.org/schema/task"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx">        

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.webapp.services.tasks">
    </context:component-scan>   
    <task:annotation-driven />    
    <bean id="scheduledMethod" class="com.myhome.myproject.web.ScheduledJobsController">         
    </bean>        
    <context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:META-INF/spring/*.properties"/>
    <context:spring-configured/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myhome.myproject">
    <context:exclude-filter expression=".*_Roo_.*" type="regex"/>
    <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"         type="annotation"/>
    </context:component-scan>
    <bean class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close"     id="dataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driverClassName}"/>
    ...
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="transactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>   
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.myhome.myproject"></context:component-scan>
    <tx:annotation-driven mode="aspectj" transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>    
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"     id="entityManagerFactory">
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="persistenceUnit"/>
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
    </beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

You declared the usage of the `tx` namespace by doing

```
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
```

But you forgot to declare the location of the xsd for this namespace in the `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute:

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
```